# Is it possible to have PowerPoint 2007 export slides to a PDF including animations?

Tags: pdf, powershell, powerpoint

I'm exporting PowerPoint presentations using PowerShell. This works fine with the Office XPS/PDF exporter plugin. However, only the complete slide, without animations, are exported.

When exporting a presentation as a web page, the presentation can be run step-by-step (e.g. revealing bullet points one by one) if you check the "Show slide animation while browsing" option (under "Web options").

Is there any way to generate a PDF with one page per animation step in the presentation, through scripting? (If not - any tips on how to do it in general?)

Answer (score 1):

When exporting to PDF it will export simple text and images so animation are not there :(

For method to generate a page per animation, you will have to explore Powerpoint object model and use some PDF generation library like iTextSharp to out put all transitions one by one.

The Powerpoint Object model is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213568(office.11).aspx)